# eBay API Search by MPN

Tags: ebay-api

I am trying to search listings on eBay by MPN via their api.

I stumbled upon this:
https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=1723
leading to `FindProducts` call

It should be able to filter products by MPN by setting `ProductID.Type=MPN`.
I tried it, but it returns products that are not related to the MPN

```
http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=FindProducts&responseencoding=XML&appid=APP_ID&siteid=0&version=829&MaxEntries=20&ProductID.Type=MPN&ProductID.Value=PLEDV1945A
```

So either i am doing something wrong, or it is returning wrong products.
Does someone know how to get listings by MPN the proper way?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have found the solution for search by MPN?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer to your question (and I haven't searched eBay by MPN before), but know that the FindProducts API call is being deprecated soon, and eBay is expecting people to use a newer API call called findItemsByProduct - [docs here](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsByProduct.html).

Also in eBay's newer Finding API family is the API call named [findItemsAdvanced](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html) which is also worth a shot.